# WordPress custom post meta filter not displaying options when filter is set

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, metadata, custom-post-type

I have two custom post types set up - "Books" and "Authors". I am using custom metadata which allows you to link a book to an author via a select box (by querying posts from the authors post type to create the select options).

This works fine, but I'm also trying to create a custom filter on the posts screen for the books post type that allows you to filter by author, which isn't behaving as expected. Here's the code I'm using to add the filter:

```
function book_filter() {
  global $typenow;
  global $wp_query;
    if ( $typenow == 'book' ) {
      $authors = new WP_Query(
        array(
          'post_type' => 'author',
          'nopaging' => true
        )
      );
      wp_reset_postdata();

      /*
      $authors = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'author',
        'numberposts' => -1
      ));
      */

      $current_author = '';
      if( isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
        $current_author = $_GET['author'];
      } ?>
      <select name="author" id="author">
        <option value="all" <?php selected( 'all', $current_author ); ?>>All authors</option>
        <?php 
        if ($authors->have_posts()) {
            while ($authors->have_posts()) {
                $authors->the_post();
                if ($current_author == get_the_ID()) {
                  echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '" selected>' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
                } else {
                  echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }

        /* foreach( $authors as $author ) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $author->ID; ?>" <?php selected( $author->ID, $current_author ); ?>><?php echo get_the_title($author->ID); ?></option>
        <?php } */

        ?>
      </select>
  <?php }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'book_filter' );

function do_book_filter( $query ) {
  global $pagenow;
  $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
  if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type == 'book' ) {
    if (isset( $_GET['author'] ) && $_GET['author'] !='all' ) {
      $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'author';
      $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['author'];
      $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';
    }
  }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'do_book_filter' );
```

Initially, all the authors are shown in the filter, and selecting an author to filter by does actually work. The problem is that, once it's been filtered, the authors disappear from the select box dropdown. I tried adding an `else` statement to `if ($authors->have_posts()) {...` and this confirmed that it isn't fetching posts from the authors post type after a filter has been set.

I'm also using another custom filter (removed from the code for simplicity) which just uses a standard array variable rather than a query and that one is working fine, so I guess it must something to do with the custom post type query.

You'll see in the code that I've tried `get_posts` (commented) as well as `WP_Query` but they both present the same issue.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: are you sure the post_type = books? because your code says "if ( $typenow == 'book' ) {"

Comment: Yes, the post type is registered as "book"